# Compactness and closed balls

Tags: metric-spaces, compactness

> Let $E$ be a compact metric space, such that $\{U_i\}_{I\in I}$ is a collection of open sets whose union is $E.$ Show that there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that any closed ball in $E$ of radius $\epsilon >0$ is entirely contained in at least one open set $U_i.$

I tried to do it by contradiction.

Suppose it is not true, then for $\epsilon >0$ there exists a closed ball $B(x_n, \epsilon)$ which is not contained in any $U_i.$ Since $E$ is compact the sequence $\{x_n\}$ has a convergent subsequence in $E$, therefore $\{x_n\} \to x$, where $x$ is the limit and $x\in E$. Thus $x\in U_i$ for some $i \in I$. Let $x\in U_{i_0}$.

How can I finish this?

Comment: Each such number is called a Lebesgue number of the covering, btw.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe I haven't went over covering just yet but thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your point $x_n$ does not depend on $n$ but on $\epsilon$; maybe you should set $\epsilon= 1/n$.

**Hint:** There exists $r>0$ such that $B(x,r) \subset U_{i_0}$. Using $x_n \to x$ and $\frac{1}{n} \to 0$, deduce that $B(x_n,1/n) \subset B(x,r) \subset U_{i_0}$ for large enough $n$.

Comment: Thanks! So to continue my proof I have to say there exists an open ball $B(x,r)$ where $r>0$ and since $x \in U_{i_0}$ then $B(x,r) \subset U_{i_0}$ but then we have that $B(x_n,1/n) \subset B(x,r) \subset U_{i_0}$ which is a contradiction?

Comment: $r$ is chosen so that $B(x,r)$, otherwise it is not necessarily true; moreover, the inclusion $B(x_n,1/n) \subset B(x,r)$ is only true for large enough $n$. It is only a hint, you have to write the argument rigorously.

Comment: Seirios thank you ! I am slowly but surely starting to understand analysis.